# Wrong tax rates for grouped products in related block

Tags: magento-1.9, tax, frontend, related-products

The shop I am working on shows wrong tax rates in related block.

Instead of the correct 19% it shows 0%.

Changing tax rates in backend leads to no effects. So I think there is no wrong configuration but some wrong return-value in

`FireGento_MageSetup_Block_Catalog_Product_Price->getFormattedTaxRate()`

This only happens for grouped products. All linked simple products have correct tax class.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the attribute "tax_class_id" will not be applied to grouped products:

[image: Attributes in Magento 1.9.1.1]

So, there can't be a value for tax percentage .... and so on.

As solution I check product type in price_info.phtml and customize output for grouped products.